# I get the error The Cloud Foundry CLI isn't installed in the IBM Cloud CLI

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I decided to host my script on the IBM Cloud service. Haven't used this service before.
I am using Windows for converging. I did everything step by step as described on the site.

Logged into my IBM Cloud account and selected the API endpoint.

```
$ ibmcloud login
```

Targeting Cloud Foundry organization and space:

```
$ ibmcloud target --cf
```

But in the third step. When needed from the get-start-python directory submit my app to IBM Cloud i am getting error when running command:

```
$ ibmcloud cf push
```

*error:*

```
$ ibmcloud cf push
Invoking 'cf push'...

FAILED
The Cloud Foundry CLI isn't installed in the IBM Cloud CLI. Use 'D:\work\IBM_Cloud_CLI\ibmcloud.exe cf install' to install it.
```

I use OS Windows 7 and through the "ibmcloud" console it starts, but I can't figure out what I haven't installed?

Answer (score 5):

With recent versions of the IBM Cloud CLI (command line interface) the Cloud Foundry CLI is no longer bundled. It needs to be installed before first use.

The command is: [`ibmcloud cf install`](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cli?topic=cli-ibmcloud_cli#ibmcloud_cf_install)

This is from your question:

```
$ ibmcloud cf push
Invoking 'cf push'...

FAILED
The Cloud Foundry CLI isn't installed in the IBM Cloud CLI. Use 'D:\work\IBM_Cloud_CLI\ibmcloud.exe cf install' to install it.
```

Do you see above that it instructs you to invoke the install command...? Go ahead :)

Comment: I installed "cf" with the command you specified. Everything was a success! But now I am getting this error:  No org targeted, use 'cf.exe target -o ORG' to target an org.
FAILED

Comment: Please upvote this answer and mark it as answered. Then create a new question - this helps finding relevant answers. In your case I would first start with `ibmcloud target --cf` to interactively set the target

Answer (score 0):

IBM cloud foundary has been depriciated as of june 2023 you can use IBM code engine istead of cloud foundary for more details please visit https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/codeengine?topic=codeengine-migrate-cf-ce-tutorial